# Unable to run a .js file in node on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js

I downloaded node.js `v0.10.36` and made a file called `helloworld.js` which contains just `console.log("Hello World!");` and it is in the same location as the node application. I enter `node helloworld.js` and it just writes out 3 dots `...` then does nothing - the [tutorial](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) I'm following doesn't really explain it and just assumes that it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: c:\> node helloworld.js will definitely work .You can choose any drive.

Comment: @Sumeet Still doesn't work, still the three dots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in the Node REPL (read-eval-print-loop). Exit the REPL by pressing `Ctrl+C` twice.

Then from the command line type `node helloworld.js` and it will work.